# Progress of a user on completion of a book

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a way to show the progress of a user on navigation through a book?

The best solution will show % of pages that user opened/completed in current book.

Answer (score 0):

My approach here would be [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag)ging all the pages of the book and show a overview of total pages / flagged pages.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how exactly the overview will be implemented. Is it going to be based on a view or some custom EntityFieldQuery(s)?